# Finding the sum $\sum_{k=1}^rk^2\binom {n-k}{r-k}$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I was stuck while finding the given summation.

$$\sum_{k=1}^rk^2\binom {n-k}{r-k}$$

Since $n$ and $r$ are both constants, so I have first converted the above summation into this:

$$\sum_{k=1}^rk^2\binom {n-k}{n-r}$$

I have no idea how to proceed next. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how to do this, but I think you're on the right track,  Work it out for some small values of $n-r$ and see if a pattern emerges.

Comment: Yeah I m trying to do that

Comment: I think I found an interesting pattern. For $r>=2$, the sum evaluates to $(n+r+1)$ times $\frac{{n+1}\choose{r-2}}{r-1}$. I wonder if someone could prove that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method is to use $k^2 = (r-k)(r-k-1) - (2r-1)(r-k) + r^2$ and 
$$P_{r}^{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n-k}{r-k} = \frac{n}{n-r+1} \, \binom{n-1}{r-1}.$$
With this one can show that, for $r\geq 2$:
\begin{align}
S_{r}^{n} &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 \, \binom{n-k}{r-k} \\
&= \frac{(n-r+2)!}{(n-r)!} \, P_{r-2}^{n} - \frac{(2r-1) \, (n-r+1)!}{(n-r)!} \, P_{r-1}^{n} + r^2 \, P_{r}^{n} \\
&= \frac{n! \, (n^2 + (r+2) \, n + r + 1)}{(r-1)! \, (n-r+3)!}  \hspace{5mm} \text{after some reduction} \\
&= \binom{n+1}{r-1} + 2 \, \binom{n+1}{r-2} \hspace{5mm} \text{after further reduction}
\end{align}

A similar result occurs when use is made of 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{r} \binom{n-k}{r-k} = \frac{n}{n-r+1} \, \binom{n-1}{r-1}.$$

Comment: The sum is from k=1 to k=r and not k=n right?

Comment: @ManishKundu The results are the same for the upper limit being either $n$ or $r$ for the summation. The example provided is for $n$ terms. The formula to be used for $r$ terms is also provided, which happens to be the same.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\sum_{k=1}^r k^2 {n-k\choose r-k}
= \sum_{k=0}^r k^2 [z^{r-k}] (1+z)^{n-k}
\\ = [z^r] \sum_{k=0}^r k^2 z^k (1+z)^{n-k}
= [z^r] (1+z)^n \sum_{k=0}^r k^2 z^k (1+z)^{-k}.$$

There is no contribution to the coefficient extractor
when $k\gt r$ and we may continue with

$$[z^r] (1+z)^n \sum_{k\ge 0} k^2 z^k (1+z)^{-k}
= [z^r] (1+z)^n
\frac{(z/(1+z))(1+z/(1+z))}{(1-z/(1+z))^3}
\\ = [z^r] (1+z)^n
z (1+z)^2 (1+z/(1+z))
= [z^r] (1+z)^n  z(1+z)(1+2z)
\\ = [z^{r-1}] (1+z)^{n+1} (1+2z).$$

This is for $r\ge 2$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{n+1\choose r-1} + 2 {n+1\choose r-2}.}$$

Alternatively,

$$\frac{n-r+3}{r-1} {n+1\choose r-2} + 2{n+1\choose r-2}
= \frac{n+r+1}{r-1} {n+1\choose r-2}.$$

Here we have used the fact that with formal power series

$$\sum_{k\ge 0} k^2 w^k  = \frac{w(1+w)}{(1-w)^3}.$$

Comment: Thanks that was helpful.